# Twitter4j returns multiple of the same Tweet

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

When using the search query "from:realdonaldtrump -filter:retweets lang:en", when searching for 100 Tweets, I receive 40 different Tweets, and then the other 60 Tweets are exactly the same. This doesn't happen when I have a query such as "computer science -filter:retweets lang:en". Does this have anything to do with how the Twitter API works, or would it be an issue with code?